# How do I access the viewControllers on the UITabbarController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to get the 2nd viewcontroller of the tabbarcontroller so i can popToRoot but Swift tells me that using an Int as a subscript is not valid and I have to use an AnyObject as an index

```
var controller = self.viewControllers[2] as! UIViewController
```

error is "Cannot subscript a value of type [AnyObject]? with an Int"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var controller = self.viewControllers![2] as! UIViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

The viewcontrollers array is zero based so the index for the 1st controller is 0 and 2nd would be 1
So fo the 2nd controller the code should be

`var controller = self.viewControllers![1] as! UIViewController`

Comment: Besides the zero-based index issue, be sure to also call out in your answer that self.viewControllers is optional. You're unwrapping it before subscripting, which is what @angel_of_code was missing and thus the error reported.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual ViewController instance:

```
var controller = self.viewControllers![0].childForScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UIViewController` nested in a `UINavigationController`:

```
if let destNav = viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
    if let destVC = destNav.children.first as? YourViewController {
        //do stuff
    }           
}
```

If you have multiple `UINavigationControllers` available, you have to test what index number to put in: `viewControllers?[0]` or `viewControllers?[2]` or whatever.

Comment: Be aware that in newer versions if Swift, if you have more than 5 or 6 tabs, the user are able to move them around them selves. This makes this approach not work, so if you have many tabs, you would need to look up the index of the navigationcontroller instead of hardcoding the index